# How does java Spring inherit built in methods from an interface?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am currently going through a Spring Boot tutorial to build a Spring Data REST application.

The EmployeeRepository interface extends the Crud Repository interface. It is then used in a DatabaseLoader where we use its save, find, and delete methods that are inherited from EmployeeRepository.
My question is how can a class use an inherited method of an interface without defining it? I always thought that on implementation of an interface I must override all of its methods.

From the tutorial: "That is how we can write an empty interface and inherit already built save, find, and delete operations."

Comment: it is no magic. Spring scans some packages (that you tell it to, either implicitly or explicitly), find all interfaces of type `CrudRepository` (for example) and then creates real classes (beans) out of those. So you program to an interface, but Spring creates the underlying implementation for you. All you need to do is follow some rules

Comment: Doesn't that just make it an abstract class?

Comment: How can it make it abstract? I dont get it

Comment: I was responding to default methods in interfaces. As far as I understand, abstract classes already have similar functionality. Why would java implement it in an interface?

Answer (score 1):

Spring data will create an implementation of that interface when the app is running and creating the necessatu beans and of course the persistance context and entity manager too
for that reason when you extends from CrudRepository you need to add the object class and the type of the id of your entity like arguments in order to create this specific object to be persisited in your database
Remember Spring Data JPA will help you with a jpa provider in this case hibernate in order to avoid EntityManagerFactory object and so on.
you can find more information about it here.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference

Answer (score 0):

EmployeeRepository is an interface in your example, not an implementation, so it need not implement the methods. The actual implementation of the interfaces you are using is being provided by Spring Data.